# TFS automated build setup for android application

Tags: android, tfs, build

I am developing an android application. TFS is used for version control. Even the automated build also needs to setup for the android app on TFS server. 
It would be great If anyone can guilde me on this.

Answer (score 1):

This is a really broad question, so I'm giving you a really broad answer:

1. Install the Java SDK, the Android SDK, and whatever you need to build your application on your build agent(s).
2. Create a custom build process template (or find one online) that can execute an ANT or Maven script.